# Update values in html table

Tags: html, ajax, html-table, esp32

I use AJAX web server on my ESP32 to display values I measure. The values consist of numbers in an array.

What is the best way to update those values? - If I am using too difficult one.

I am tring to make work this code, but I dont understand what is the problem, since this is a bit over my knowledge.

```
void handlevalues() {
    server.send(200, "text/plane", String(strd[0][0]) + "," + String(strd[0][1]) + "," + String(strd[1][0]) + "," + String(strd[1][1]));   
    //and so on
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206396/discussion-on-question-by-fhanus-update-values-in-html-table).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to send multiple response to a single request so it will return only one value.
You have to send only one string. In order to do this, you can find the format that suits you the best (e.g. JSON or CSV or PUG)